# SSRS 2008 week number calculation of current month

Tags: reporting-services

I need to construct a data parameter in SSRS 2008 where if the current week number is 1 then I use the first day of the previous month and if not then I use the current day.

I.e. today is week 4 therefore would utilize today's date

If today was march 2, then the week would be week 1 and I would utilize the first of the previous month, feb 1

note: weeks must follow calendar weeks.

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parameter default using the following expression:

```
=IIf(Day(Today()) <=7
    and DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today(), FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)
      >= DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1), FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)
  , DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1))
  , Today())
```

So:

If today is one of the first seven days of the month, and the day of the week number is >= the day of the week of the first of the month

=> First week, so use the first day of the previous month

=> Else use the current date.